# Could applying ridge regression on small dataset improve predictive power?

Tags: predictive-models, least-squares, ridge-regression

Suppose I have a small data set $X$ that is $30\times6$. I am wondering if it makes sense to use ridge regression if I want to improve the predicting power of the model.

To my understanding, ridge regression can usually be used to solve the following problems:

1. The data matrix $X$ is singular. In this case, OLS does not work.
2. We have too many features. Ridge regression's objective function puts penalty on size of features, meaning $\sum \|\beta_i\|^2$.

However, I am wondering if the following reasoning makes sense:

> OLS estimators are unbiased and have the least variance among all unbiased estimators. Since I have a very small data set, my OLS estimators have very big variance. Even though they are unbiased, since I do not have a big data set, the predicting power might still be low. By using ridge regression, I no longer have unbiased estimators, but a high value of $\lambda$ will give me estimators that have lower variance. As a result, it is *possible* that I end up with a model that has better predicting power.

Comment: I think "penalty on number of features" more describes LASSO, and is not really true for ridge regression.

Comment: With 30 observations and 6 features, I think your best answer is actually applying both methods and testing which does a better job instead of guessing which theory might fit better. Ridge regression helps when there are a large number of multicollinear features which make it difficult to model small datasets.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Sorry. I meant to say "size of features"

Comment: It certainly could work. For any given sample size, the optimal amount of $L_2$ penalty is positive (so not zero). That is, there exists a positive $\lambda$ such that ridge will do better than OLS in terms of mean squared error. See Dave Giles blog post ["A Regression "Estimator" that Minimizes MSE"](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2011/08/overly-confident-future-nobel-laureate.html).

Comment: @RichardHardy This sounds like a really nice result. Knowing existence is always good.

Comment: Prediction of what? You want to increase predictive power, but without knowing what you are predicting, the question is empty. Prediction usually means a future event in a time series. It can mean prediction of AUC, and for regularization it should because the primary application of regularization is to treat ill-posed integrals.. It can mean prediction of optimal covariance, it can mean a lot of things. So, pick your poison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning does make sense.

Given a correctly specified linear model, the optimal amount of $L_2$ penalty is positive, for any given sample size. That is, there exists a positive $\lambda$ such that ridge will do better than OLS in terms of mean squared error of estimated parameters; see Dave Giles blog post ["A Regression "Estimator" that Minimizes MSE"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2013/10/a-regression-estimator-that-minimizes.html) for details. If you are able to estimate $\lambda$ precisely enough, ridge will yield more precise estimates than OLS, which in turn will improve prediction accuracy.

Without the assumption of a correctly specified model, things are less straightforward, but ridge may still be a good alternative. You may test the performance of ridge vs. OLS on a test sample and see for yourself which one does better.